# How to set up root and home routes in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up a React app and I'm confused about how to have a root route and a home route.

It makes sense to me to set up a Root layout to manage shared page elements (nav, for example) and then use  to pull in specific page content. But I can't figure out how that would work for the home page if the Root route is attached to "/".

Here are my routes

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/login",
        element: <Login />,
      },
      {
        path: "/register",
        element: <Register />,
      },
    ]
  },
]);
```

Here is my Root file

```
export default function Root() {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
      <Link to={`/`}><img className="logo" src={ logo } alt="logo" /></Link>
        <nav className="global-nav">
          <ul>
            <li><Link to={`login`}>Login</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={`register`}>Register</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={`about`}>About</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You typically use [`index`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#index) on the _home_ route